# Can I play Metroid Prime for Wii U just using gamepad?

Tags: wii-u, wiimote, metroid-prime-trilogy

Or is it wiimote + nunchack required?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't. For all original Wii games, the original control schemes are still required.

Comment: That is correct. Also, I can confirm that even if there is an unlikely exception, Metroid Prime (Trilogy) is *not* one of them.